# Git diff --name-only and copy that list

Tags: git

I just want to get a list of changed files between two revisions, which is simple:

```
git diff -–name-only commit1 commit2 > /path/to/my/file
```

But, what should I write, if I want copy all that listed files to another place? And I need completely identical directory structure for copied files.

For example, I have modified and added files:

```
/protected/texts/file1.txt
/protected/scripts/index.php
/public/pics/pic1.png
```

I want to have in `/home/changes/` all those changed and added files:

```
/home/changes/protected/texts/file1.txt
/home/changes/protected/scripts/index.php
/home/changes/public/pics/pic1.png
```

Comment: i don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve … propagating changes to different clones? creating patches? patching files outside a git repository?

Comment: Not patch, but exact copy structure of changed files. Like patch, but with solid files

Comment: And yes, patching files outside git repository - closest target for me :)

Comment: sorry. WHAT? you want to capture and replay changes to files and changes to trees? that's a patch. `git format-patch` can do this for commit ranges.

Comment: `git diff commit1 commit2 > my.patch` and then `cd other/path; patch -p1 < my.patch`. Why does it have to be done with full copies of the files? If it's because you think the patch might not apply, and therefore the other directory isn't really in the `commit1` state, you really ought to copy *everything* from the `commit2` state...

Comment: Fun fact: I copy pasted `git diff -–name-only ` from OP to run it on my machine, and it failed. It turns out that the two dashes are not both really dashes:
"-–name-only".charCodeAt(0)
45
"-–name-only".charCodeAt(1)
8211

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Try the following command, which I have tested:

```
$ cp -pv --parents $(git diff --name-only) DESTINATION-DIRECTORY
```

Comment: Thanks for the ``cp --parents`` hint, I've wanted that option for years and never knew it existed!  ..obviously I never bothered to look for it either =\

Comment: Note that this does not work on Mac, as the `--parents` option of `cp` is not available.

Comment: Any tips on using this if files have unusual characters? Whitespace, nordic characters.

Comment: @HalvorStrand, I haven't tested it, but setting `IFS=$'\n'` first may do it.  (Preferably in a subshell so as not to mess up your original IFS value.)

Comment: I'm getting an error `cp: cannot stat 'git diff --name-only': No such file or directory` on git bash on windows. What am I doing wrong? Destination-directory exists

Comment: @Shiva Are you sure you've used the character `  instead of the character ' ?

Comment: For anyone looking: `rsync -R $(git diff --name-only) DESTINATION-DIRECTORY` worked well for me on a Mac.

Answer (score 18):

The following should work fine:

```
git diff -z --name-only commit1 commit2 | xargs -0 -IREPLACE rsync -aR REPLACE /home/changes/protected/
```

To explain further:

- The `-z` to with `git diff --name-only` means to output the list of files separated with NUL bytes instead of newlines, just in case your filenames have unusual characters in them.
- The `-0` to `xargs` says to interpret standard input as a NUL-separated list of parameters.
- The `-IREPLACE` is needed since by default `xargs` would append the parameters to the end of the `rsync` command.  Instead, that says to put them where the later `REPLACE` is.  (That's a nice tip from [this Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/43432/rsync-files-from-equivalent/43449#43449).)
- The `-a` parameter to `rsync` means to preserve permissions, ownership, etc. if possible.  The `-R` means to use the full relative path when creating the files in the destination.

*Update:* if you have an old version of `xargs`, you'll need to use the `-i` option instead of `-I`.  (The former is deprecated in later versions of `findutils`.)

Comment: That's strange - what operating system are you using?  If it's a Linux distribution, which one, and what does `xargs --version` say?

Comment: Ah, in that version of xargs you need to use `-i` instead, which is deprecated in later versions - 4.1 is quite old now.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Mark: I remember reading somewhere that you need a space after `-I` in some versions, so maybe try `-I REPLACE` instead.

Comment: Never mind.  That doesn't work either.  `-I` is only supported since `findutils` 4.2.10, released December 2004.

Comment: You should add `--diff-filter=d` to exclude deleted files from the list. Otherwise you'll end up getting errors while trying to copy them into the changes folder. Otherwise great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Here's a one-liner:

List changed files & pack them as *.zip:

```
git diff --name-only | zip patched.zip -@
```

List last committed changed files & pack them as *.zip:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD | zip patched.zip -@
```

Comment: If you are using windows you can download commandline zip from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zip/

Comment: @Radon8472 That installs `sed.exe` ? I'm still getting `zip` not found on windows.

Comment: no, the link is pointing to the download for zip.exe not for sed.
If you cant use zip in commandline, you should add the folder where the zip.exe is installed to your `PATH` env variable.

Answer (score 6):

```
zip update.zip $(git diff --name-only commit commit)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Target directory
TARGET=/target/directory/here

for i in $(git diff --name-only)
    do
        # First create the target directory, if it doesn't exist.
        mkdir -p "$TARGET/$(dirname $i)"
        # Then copy over the file.
        cp -rf "$i" "$TARGET/$i"
    done
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/79061/sebastian-paaske-t%c3%b8rholm

Comment: thank you; i'm using this piece of code to copy the modified files to another directory

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly.

```
git diff 1526043 82a4f7d --name-only | xargs zip update.zip

git diff 1526043 82a4f7d --name-only | xargs -n 10 zip update.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

No one has mentioned `cpio` which is easy to type, creates hard links, and handles spaces in filenames:

```
git diff --name-only $from..$to  | cpio -pld outdir
```