# Automate Azure Devops (FTP Upload) and Git to upload on Remote Server

Tags: azure-devops, ftp, devops, sftp

The current setup is as below

- Version Control - Git
- Repos and Branch hosted on - Azure DevOps
- Codebase - External server

The dev team clones Azure Repo into local git project and any staged changes are committed via Git and pushed to specific branch of Azure DevOps. In this setup we would want to upload the changes to external FTP servers and avoid manual upload. Currently trying to use Azure Devops FTP Upload Task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops), however facing issues; yaml script as below

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.4
  webAppName: 'Test Project'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureRepoName
  artifact: Test Project Deploy

- task: FtpUpload@2
  displayName: 'FTP Upload'
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: inputs
    serverUrl: 'ftps://00.00.00.00:22'
    username: ftp-username
    password: ftp-password
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureRepoName'
    remoteDirectory: '/home/public_html'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: true
```

**PROBLEM**

Following errors occur when I commit (for test purposes) something.

```
Starting: PublishPipelineArtifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Pipeline Artifacts
Description  : Publish (upload) a file or directory as a named artifact for the current run
Version      : 1.199.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact
==============================================================================
Artifact name input: Test Project Deploy
##[error]Path does not exist: /home/vsts/work/1/s/AzureRepoName
Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact
```

I want to upload any staged change that is committed to main branch on Azure Devops to be automatically deploy on the remote FTP server

Thanks

Comment: What have you done to attempt to troubleshoot and solve the issue on your own? The error message is telling you the exact problem: The path doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried using different variables to repo path but could not figure out what variable to use to specify the correct path so that the staged changes are uploaded on FTP server after every commit to main branch

Comment: You can check the current path with `cd`, for example with `echo %cd%`.

Comment: It just says `/home/vsts/work/1`, not sure if it is not working due to incorrect path or some other error

Answer (score 0):

On checkout devops agent will create /home/vsts/work/1/s/AzureRepoName folder with your source but actually when the checkout happens the /home/vsts/work/1/s folder is the repository root i.e. there is no AzureRepoName folder in there. so what you need is to publish /home/vsts/work/1/s folder itself as the artifact. also your ftp upload task should use `rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureRepoName'`

Comment: No, my assumption is that for any staged commit pipeline will fetch the changes from Azure Repo and upload to specific folder on FTP server

Comment: What i meant was that devops pipeline checks out your repo at /home/vsts/work/1/s AKA $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) which is actually the git repo and not $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzureRepoName. Therefore the artifact task is failing. you shoud try changing your artifact task to publish $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the repo path using `'$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and with some changes in ftp was able to upload. However, this script uploaded all the files and folders at specified path. Any way that we can only upload committed changes to FTP instead of uploading the whole repo?

Comment: not quite sure why you want to copy changed files only but you could try something like `$ cp -pv --parents $(git diff --name-only) DESTINATION-DIRECTORY` to copy changed/added files to the destination folder and then upload that folder. you can play around with the diff command to get files changed from last commit. checkout [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605347/git-diff-name-only-and-copy-that-list)

Comment: I only want to upload last commit to specific folder path on FTP server and not whole working directory, the same way we do git push and it only pushes the last changes to specific files and not upload all the files/folders. Would need to sync the change to remote server which means keeping the same file path in repo content

Comment: on the dev-ops agent there are no pending changes because it will fetch whatever is in the repository. Please try the suggestions from that post is suggested, git diff should give you the list of files that changed and you can pipe that to copy command to copy them to a temp directory from where you can upload them. if you cannot get it to work then i will try to create a sample for you